# Dell Latitude 7390 Business Laptop hangs randomly when powered it on

Tags: linux, grub2, dell-latitude

I have Latitude 7390 Business Laptop purchased 3 years ago. Windows has been removed and Ubuntu 20.04 has been installed on it.

Normally, when I power it on, the Dell Logo appears for a few seconds. Then the GRUB menus appears to ask me to choose a kernel to boot.

However, for the past few months, sometimes my laptop hangs at the Dell Logo and nothing happens for hours -- I tried to leave it there to see what happens. The only way out is to push the power button to turn it off and turn it on again.

It does not happen very often, but I am worried if this mean something is wrong with the hardware. Is there anyway to diagnose what is wrong?

Comment: Are any USB devices plugged in? If so, unplug them before booting.

Comment: @user9938 No. I have nothing plugged in.

Comment: Backip your data if you haven't already. Then test both the memory and hard drive.

Comment: Any idea of how to do the test?

Comment: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000179493/dell-diagnostic-tools-to-diagnose-and-fix-hardware-problems-on-your-dell-pc-tablet-or-servers